# Remove fade in/out effect during UIView TransitionFlipFromLeft animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview

I'm using quite a standard way of animating flip transition on a view. The code below should be self explanatory

```
    let option: UIViewAnimationOptions = self.flipped ? .TransitionFlipFromLeft : .TransitionFlipFromRight
    UIView.transitionWithView(self.spotImageView, duration: 2, options: option, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.spotImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }) { (finished) -> Void in
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
```

You can see this really unnecessary fade in/out effect on the gif. Unfortunately, my reputation doesn't allow me to post images directly, so the gif can be found here
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9rl4ftwxhqn1nps/flip.gif?dl=0

How can I get rid of this black fade in/out effect?

Comment: My guess is Apple is fading to black so the transition looks good on a black background. It looks bad with any other color background though. Open a bug report.